# React event currentTarget textContent showing all values

Tags: reactjs

Somehow `event.currentTarget.textContent` showing all results when select

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.textContent);
}

render() {

    var items = [];
    for (var key in this.props.data) {
        items.push(<option key={key} value={key}>{this.props.data[key].name}</option>);
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value=''>Default</option>
                {items}
            </select>
        </div>

    );
}
```

console log result is: `DefaultCategory1Category2Cateogry3` How do I grab selected options text?

example: value shows value but currentTarget shows all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/3q2bswLy/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a `select` element can be accessed using `ELEMENT.value`.

Using `ELEMENT.textContent` will give you all of the content of the child-elements of that element (which is actually a string contains all the values in the `<option>` elements).

The following is a general javascript example, but it works for the react `event.currentTarget` exactly the same:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('select').value);
console.log(document.querySelector('select').textContent);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>val1</option>
  <option selected="selected">val2</option>
  <option>val3</option>
</select>
```

Check the following jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p89a6r3L/

Comment: no luck :( still showing all results but from another dropdown component when using "document.querySelector('select').textContent"

Comment: @JohnnyDerp check the link in my answer

Comment: yea, problem is my option value and texts are different here I updated yours: https://jsfiddle.net/p89a6r3L/6/

Comment: So you need to use `event.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].textContent`